# Multiple Forgone Job Opportunities and Economic Profit

Tags: microeconomics

I'm told that forgone job opportunities are implicit costs, to be included in calculating economic profit, but I can't seem to see how I could list and consider many different forgone opportunities. My question here is how do we do so?

For example, if I have a piece of land or big city real estate, there could be a great many different uses for it. If I considered each of these forgone opportunities an implicit cost, I would think the expression of my economic costs would be useless to me.

So I suspect that either I'm suffering from an oversimplified ECON101 explanation of implicit and opportunity costs or simply an incorrect one. Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: See this https://www.econlib.org/library/Topics/College/opportunitycost.html

Answer (score -1):

We don't use all possible opportunity costs. We only use the cost of forgoing the next-best-alternative.

Comment: There are two mistakes in your answer: First, opportunity cost is defined as the *value* (not the cost) of the next best alternative. Second, the cost (or value, for that matter) of the other (lower-ranked) alternatives are not opportunity cost.

Comment: @HerrK. Good distinction.